# How do I represent stripe transaction amount for example `-94769` to actual money value e.g `99.18 USD`

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-5.7

I have this code in laravel which pull current day transaction in stripe

```
    $dateCurrent = strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s'));

    $this->transactions = \Stripe\BalanceTransaction::all([
        'available_on' => [
            'lte' => "{$dateCurrent}",
        ],
        'currency' => 'USD'
    ]);

    foreach ($this->transactions->data as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 0) {
            $time = date('d', $value->available_on);
        }

        if ($time == date('d', $value->available_on)) {
            $this->trans[] = $value;
            $transactionCount = $key;
        }
    }
```

and then I am trying to add all amounts for every transactions like this,

```
    $total = 0;

    foreach ($this->trans as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 0) {
            $total = $value->amount;
        } elseif ($value->status == 'available') {
            $total = bcadd($value->amount, $total);
        }
    }

    dump($total);
```

Upon writing this code, I got a result of `-94769`.

Am I doing it right?
How do I represent `-94769` to actual money value e.g `99.18 USD`?

My references on this is base on stripe API at the following links

https://stripe.com/docs/api?&lang=php#charge_object
https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#zero-decimal

This is the first time I will integrate payment method on web application. So I need deeper understanding about money.

Comment: I am totally not familiar with that system, but you are surely doing something wrong... those values just don't match in any way.

Comment: Its just example.. if you're talking about -94769 and 99.18 USD.. 99.18 USD is not derived from -94769 because that what i am asking how to.

Answer (score 1):

"Amount" in the Stripe API always represents the smallest unit of your default currency. So, it is cents for USD, or Yen for JPY.

Assuming your currency is USD, you can convert any Amount to dollars simply by dividing by 100.